# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only for primary keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, primary-key, unique-key

Is there a way to restrict "ON DUPLICAYE KEY UPDATE" to only trigger if the duplicate key is the PRIMARY KEY of the table? (and not if the conflict is generated by a UNIQUE KEY)

For example in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(16) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (username)
);
```

I would like to trigger the update only if the `id` column generate the conflict, and throw an error as usual in case the conflict happened because of the unique key `username`.

**Edit**:

I'm working on a very simple PHP framework. Previously I had a single method `save()` that discriminated between `INSERT` and `UPDATE` based on the presence of the `id` property on the object on which it was called.

Now I rewrote this method using the `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query, but when I try to insert (for example) a user  with an already existing `username` value, it updates that user instead of throwing an error.

I know this is the correct behaviour, I just wanted to know if there's a way to achieve the same result only on the PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: I am assuming that should have read `UNIQUE(username)`?

Comment: @Uueerdo yes sorry, I updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`on duplicate key` triggers for both primary keys and unique keys.

In your case, the primary key is an auto-incremented column, so you should not be inserting a value.  Period.

Hence, you can get the behavior you want by simply not including the `on duplicate key` clause and leaving out the `id` from the `insert`.

Comment: I didn't explain myself enough. I've updated the question, but your answer seems pretty clear _"triggers for both primary keys and unique keys"_

Comment: @Sneppy . . . I'm going to emphasize that you should not be passing the `id` into an `insert`, because the database sets it automatically.

Comment: actually I never said I'm providing the `id` value as well in the insert query

Comment: @Sneppy if you're not specifying the id, it should never generate the conflict.

Comment: @Uueerdo yes, it generates the conflict on the `username` column and thus update that row. Anyway that table was just an example. I was looking for a far more general solution, that's way I wanted to differentiate between primary key and unique keys.

Comment: you can add the id as null or 0 and it will use the auto increment, so you can do that. if id > 0 it will use the update key, in case on id being 0 or null auto increment will be used. 

That said, with multiple unique keys, this can be a security issue, an user table for example. a sign up form with same email address as admin could overwrite the password or something like that. so, it's depending on situation...

It is recommended to use this feature with only one KEY primary or unique

Source
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/auto_increment/#setting-explicit-values